# How to you evaluate ${\int \frac{1}{z\left(z-1\right)\left(z-3\right)}dz}$ using the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

> How to you evaluate $${\int\limits_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z\left(z-1\right)\left(z-3\right)}dz}$$ using the Residue Theorem.

This problem has been driving me crazy, I am supposed to apply the Residue formula for double poles, but I can't figure out how. I would appreciate help.

Comment: What contour are you integrating over?

Comment: Also note that, as currently written, your function does not have any double poles. Only $3$ simple poles (poles of order $1$) at ${z=0}$, ${z=1}$ and ${z=3}$

Comment: Do you know how to calculate residues at $z=0$ and $z=1$?  Do you understand what the residue is in terms of the series expansion?

Comment: @Nikolay Cherednychenko Apologies if I'm wrong but your name seems russian. I can understand russian pretty well (writing is not my forte though), so if it's easier for you to write things in russian, I'd be glad too help as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy intgeral theorem:
$$\mathcal{I}:=\oint_{\lvert z\rvert =2}\frac{1}{z\left(z-1\right)\left(z-3\right)}dz$$ $$=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left[\frac{1}{z\left(z-1\right)\left(z-3\right)}\right]+\operatorname{Res}_{z=1}\left[\frac{1}{z\left(z-1\right)\left(z-3\right)}\right]\right).$$

Evaluating these residues yields
$$\mathcal{I}=2\pi i(1/3-1/2)=-\frac{\pi i}{3}$$

Comment: @NikolayCherednychenko Do you understand how I calculated the residues or should I elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a double pole.   You have simple poles at $0,1$ and $3$.  The residues are $1/3,-1/2$ and $1/6$, respectively.

If the contour encloses all three poles, you get $2\pi i (1/3-1/2+1/6)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify the contour |z|=2

Comment: Adjusting for that gives you  $-\pi i/3$, as the simple pole at $3$ isn't included.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that